# Not quite a transpose

Tags: pandas

Hello I wanted reshape my existing df:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id 1 | a | b | c |
| id 2 | x | y | z |

to the following:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
|  |  |
| id 1 | a |
| id 1 | b |
| id 1 | c |
| id 2 | x |
| id 2 | y |
| id 2 | z |

Basically it's like a transpose but keeps the columns as columns and  appends the values from column B to the last column under column B and repeats the corresponding id value the column A for that row.

I'm new to pandas but tried a few basic functions like concat, but this use case is slightly different

Comment: you want `df.melt()`